# JNLP with Custom Progress - loads applet classes before displaying progress

Tags: java, progress-bar, jnlp, progress, java-web-start

I have a JNLP that specifies a number of resource jars. One has the download="progress" to display a custom progress bar as other resource jars are loaded. The progress is found and displayed as expected, however it waits to display progress until after four of the other jars are loaded as well (these are 3MB). It then shows the progress for the rest of the resources (another 4MB) I expected the progress jar to load first and display before starting downloads of the main jar and any dependency jars. The jars that are loaded seem to contain the classes that are directly referenced by the "main" jar whereas the progress jar is only a few KB and has no dependencies/imports on any other jar in resources.

Is there a way to configure JNLP to download only the progress jar first and display it and then grab the rest of the resources?

Comment: According to section 4.4 of the JNLP spec., the download attribute has two values 'eager' and 'lazy'.  This is backed up by the DTD supplied with the JNLP Spec.  E.G. <!ATTLIST jar download (eager | lazy) "eager">.  Where did the 'progress' value come from?

Answer (score 1):

By default all  resources are downloaded eagerly;

So have you tried this:  specify "lazy"   on all your other .jars
Then maybe the download="progress" one will get preference and be downloaded first.
Also try putting the progress one first in the list.

Some examples here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/customizeRIALoadingExperience.html

There is also a property jnlp.concurrentDownloads which you could tweak and might have an effect.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/riaJnlpProps.html

Answer (score 0):

It was feature newly implemented in 1.6.0_18:

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr056/jnlp-6.0.18.html

Comment: Huhh.  OK that is new to me.  You might have to prepare a test case and submit it to the Oracle Bug DB - see what the official word is.  Do you have a sand-boxed, publicly available version of this failure available for people to throw a browser at?  (Given the resource sizes, I doubt many will - but it does not hurt to offer one.)